# Where is my task with no assignee or project in Asana?

Tags: asana

It didn't have a project and I removed myself as the assignee, now I can't find it anywhere.  I can only sort by project or assignee.  Anyone know where it is hiding?

Comment: And if you don't know what it is called? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163905/how-can-i-view-all-tasks-with-no-assignee-and-no-project-in-asana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

When a task is not assigned to anyone, is not in a project, and does not have a tag, you can still find it by searching for it by name in your workspace.

Answer (score 9):

I don't work for Asana, but I found that you can search by assigned to "Nobody" which helps me find lost tasks.

Comment: Great tip! I combined that with project = "No Project", saved the search and how have a convenient catch-all for this seemingly bad user experience (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Search and click on "Unassociated Tasks" at the bottom of the drop-down.

Comment: There is no more such option