# How can I view all tasks with no assignee and no project in Asana?

Tags: asana

Especially if I don't know its name. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055051/where-is-my-task-with-no-assignee-or-project-in-asana)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the new search (announced in http://blog.asana.com/2013/04/asana-search-views/#more-1188)

1. Click the drop-down button on the search field.
2. Search for "Assigned to `Nobody`; In projects `No Project`" (both fields will autocomplete from "No")
3. Click search, see your results, rejoice!

Comment: They've made it a premium feature now. So there is no way to do it